# Are JavaScript functions in different <script>s in global scope?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a situation like this in an HTML file:

```
<script>
  var my_function = function(param)
  {
    alert(param);
  }
</script>

<div>
  <!-- snip -->

  <script>
    $(function() {
      my_function("Hello world!");
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Will `my_function` be in scope in the second `<script>`? Wouldn't `my_function` be in global scope?

Comment: @ Close voters: Why is this question being flagged as off-topic? In my opinion, the question I'm asking is about the behavior of JavaScript within the context of web programming, which is within StackOverflow's scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will be, since it’s on the global object (as `window.my_function`).

It will also be ”in scope” (not really meaningful to check, but `delete window.my_function` won’t work, for example).

Answer (score 1):

All scripts that execute on a page share the same document and window element. So yes. they execute in order, and they are all in the document scope.

Answer (score 1):

`my_function` as defined in your code is added to the `global` scope. It will be available in all contexts. This is also how libraries can be made use of. Consider that the script tag contains executable code wether the code is inline:

```
<script>code</script>
```

or references remote code:

```
<script src="my_code.js"></script>
```

So when you add a script like jQuery or backbone to your html page you are effectively adding their contents to the pages execution context and can access them from your own code.